# Rock,Paper,Scissors Game on Codecademy

Tags: javascript

I tried to incorporate the additional suggestions given on the website(Codecademy), viz. the feature in which there's a tie and the provision for taking input again. This is the error-containing piece of code:

```
var userChoice, computerChoice;

var choicesDetermination = function(){
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    if(userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors"){
        userChoice = prompt("Invalid input. Please try again.\n Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    }
    computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } 
    console.log("User: " + userChoice);
    console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 === choice2){
        console.log("The result is a tie! Let's try one more time.");
        choicesDetermination();
        compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock"){
        if(choice2 === "scissors"){
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else{
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else{
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(choice1 === "scissors"){
            if(choice2 === "paper"){
                return "scissors wins";
            }
            else{
                return "rocks wins";
            }
        }
    }
}
choicesDetermination();
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Here, choicesDetermination() is the function in which I've taken the input and stored them in userChoice, computerChoice(both global variables).
I don't know why but the code seems to run fine when I ask for the input again; the variables are changed correctly. But the function compare() doesn't run correctly; the return statements don't get printed to screen.

Comment: what are the values of choice1 and choice2

Comment: The way this code is organized seems very fishy. You're using recursion for no apparent reason, and global variables `userChoice` and `computerChoice` in addition to local ones `choice1` and `choice2`. Something is very very wrong. What's the rest of the code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this part "the return statements don't get printed to screen". I see that you are running `console.log`, which will only run in your console, not in your browser per se.

Comment: When the first time there's a tie, I ask again for the input. But when input is entered again, the "who wins" statement doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've always found with Code Academy is that the output strings have to be annoyingly perfect, so check that first!

I think the issue with your code is that you're actually supposed to `return "The result is a tie! Let's try one more time."` **not** `console.log`.

Please find my complete, passing code below:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (userChoice != "rock" && "scissors" && "paper") {
    alert("Please enter 'rock', 'scissors', or 'paper' as shown.");
    userChoice = prompt("Type carefully, please: Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
}
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins"; 
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```